# Unclear polygons when rendering

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I am learning to work in a blender. Finishing the next project on the render, I noticed these polygons. I tried to add thick, it didn't help. This problem manifests itself only when I run the render (cycles). What could be the problem?

Solid
[image]

Rendered
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quads are made of tris, so when the face is twisted you may see this kind of artefacts, if you want to avoid you can try to enable the *Auto Smooth* option in the *Properties panel > Object Data > Normals*.